# Show missing data in a jittered plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, na, jitter, naniar

I have data from a questionnaire. It has 10 items, where one can score 0 or 1 in each item. Due to time pressure, many items, especially the last ones, were not answered, which is intended and counts as a score of 0. However, I want to preserve the `NA`s for visualizing them.

My goal is a plot that shows the raw data points jittered and some overlaid mean + error bars per item. The `NA` points should be plotted as well, at the side and in a different color, much like `naniar::geom_miss_point()` does. I have almost achieved this by overlaying `geom_miss_point()` and `geom_jitter()`. See the plots below.

###### example data creation

not important, just copy paste

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(naniar)
set.seed(1)

# create weights for adding NAs later
# items have more NAs if their position is later

weights <- numeric()
for (i in 1:10) {
  weights <- c(weights, rep(i, i))
}

s <- seq(0, 590, by = 10)
na <- s + sample(weights, 
                 size = length(s),
                 replace = TRUE)

na2 <- s + sample(weights,
           size = length(s),
           replace = TRUE)

na3 <- unique(c(na, na2))

item <- rep(1:10, 60) |> as.factor()
score <- runif(600) |> round()
score[na3] <- NA
id <- rep(1:60, each = 10)
dat <- data.frame(id, item, score)

# compute a separate score where NA are counted as zero
dat$na_score <- dat$score
dat$na_score[is.na(dat$score)] <- 0
```

###### A) Perfect Jitter plot like I want it, but no `NA` shown

using `geom_jitter()`

[image: plotA]

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(y = item, x = score)) +
  geom_jitter(height = 0.2, width = 0.05, alpha = 0.3) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal",
               geom = "errorbar",
               aes(x = na_score)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean,
               geom = "point",
               color = "red",
               aes(x = na_score)) +
  labs(subtitle = "mean score (red) and 95% CI error bars\nmean + error bars count NA as zero")
```

###### B) `NA`s shown, but jitter is only applied to `NA` and not normal data points :(

using `geom_miss_point()`

This is nice, because it shows how `NA`s are dragging down the mean score.

[image: plotB]

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(y = item, x = score)) +
  geom_miss_point(alpha = 0.08) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal",
               geom = "errorbar",
               aes(x = na_score)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean,
               geom = "point",
               color = "red",
               size = 1,
               aes(x = na_score)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue","black")) +
  labs(subtitle = "mean score (red) and 95% CI error bars\nmean + error bars count NA as zero")
```

###### C) Cheating by overlaying A and B (Almost Desired Output)

This is close to my desired output, but ideally `NA` and normal points would have the same jitter, both horizontally and vertically. The main concern here is that normal data points are plotted twice, once as a jitter in `geom_jitter()` and once with `geom_miss_point()`. It would be easily hidden by tweaking alpha, but I exaggerated it to show the problem here.

[image: plotC]

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(y = item, x = score)) +
  geom_miss_point(alpha = 0.08) +
  geom_jitter(height = 0.2, width = 0.05, alpha = 0.1) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal",
               geom = "errorbar",
               aes(x = na_score)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean,
               geom = "point",
               color = "red",
               size = 1,
               aes(x = na_score)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue","black")) +
  labs(subtitle = "mean score (red) and 95% CI error bars\nmean + error bars count NA as zero")
```

How can I achieve my desired output?

`?geom_miss_point` mentions the use of `ggobi` methods` to plot two things on the same axis. Maybe this is a way to go.

Comment: Why jittered points rather than just printing the number of obervations at 0 and 1?

Comment: What can I imagine do you mean by "just printing the number of obs." ? You mean, like, literal digits? Or something along the lines of a bar chart. The latter is no good because I can not show the mean + the number of obs. on the same graph if they don't share the same axis. I also thought about some better density colouring, do you have any idea?

Comment: I mean just digits, perhaps with the number of `NA` in brackets afterwards. It may not be quite as pretty, but it would be much clearer for a viewer to understand.

Comment: I am looking for something pretty and understandable that shows the real data and not just summary stats, so this is the best I was able to come up with. The jitter makes more sense visually if there are notable differences in sample size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I miss something. But one option would be to plot the missing and non-missing data using just one `geom_jitter` without the need of `geom_miss_point`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat$x <- dat$score
dat$x[is.na(dat$x)] <- -.1

ggplot(dat, aes(y = item, x = score)) +
  geom_jitter(
    aes(x = x, color = !is.na(score)),
    height = 0.2, width = 0.05, alpha = 0.1
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = "mean_cl_normal",
    geom = "errorbar",
    aes(x = na_score)
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    fun = mean,
    geom = "point",
    color = "red",
    size = 1,
    aes(x = na_score)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "missing",
    values = c("blue", "black"),
    labels = c("Missing", "Not missing")
  ) +
  labs(subtitle = "mean score (red) and 95% CI error bars\nmean + error bars count NA as zero")
```

[image]

Comment: Changing all `NA`s to -0.1 to have them left of 0 is clever. This is a great solution so far. My only problem now is that the legend is indistinguishable. What could we do about it?

Comment: This is the trick I borrowed from geom_miss_point. :D For the legend use `+guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))` to remove the transparency in the legend.

Comment: Perfect! This definitely does the trick, and is great to hear that there is no deeper magic in `geom_miss_point()` that we are now missing with this solution.